# Failure notice with my mail server, what to do?

Tags: email-server, spf

I've build a simple Mail server for my personal use, but Google reject my emails whatever I do.

I worked hard finding the initials problems (wrong SPF entries in the DNS), but now, everything seems fine, and I still got this kind of messages from Gmail :

> Am 22/10/13 14:20 schrieb "MAILER-DAEMON@myserver.ovh.net" unter
>   :
>
> > Hi. This is the qmail-send program at myserver.ovh.net.
> >     I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following
> >     addresses.
> >     This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.
> >
> > :
> >     2607:f8a0:4d0d:0c05:0000:0000:0000:001a failed after I sent the message.
> >     Remote host said: 550-5.7.1 [2001:41d0:8:62e0::1      12] Our system has
> >     detected that this
> >     550-5.7.1 message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of
> >     spam sent
> >     550-5.7.1 to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit
> >     550-5.7.1
> >     http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for
> >     550 5.7.1 more information. w14si9673617qeu.76 - gsmtp

My domain is mediafins.com, here's the SPF entry related to it :

> v=spf1 a mx ip4:37.59.15.224 ~all

(The ip is the IP to my server).

I also tried this (interesting tool) : http://mxtoolbox.com/public/tools/findproblems.aspx?filter=37.59.15.224/29&source=findmonitors&domain=mediafins.com

The only problems are related to HTTPS, everything else is good.

Having "everything else good" is what bother me : if it's good, why Google still reject my emails ??

What did I do wrong ? Do I have to add a SPF also to mail.mediafins.com, my MX DNS entry ?

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you also have a IPv6 address? It seems that you mail server uses this address for sending mail.

If so then one of the solutions can be to remove the SPF record (at least temporary to see if it helps).

The other one to also list you IPv6 address (or in this case you provider's), not just your IPv4 address.